# choosing step sizes when fitting under python

Tags: python, data-fitting, lmfit

As you may know, the lmfit module in python is convenient to extend capabilities of scipy.optimize functionnalities.

However I don't find something that seems to me necessary: the possibility to choose the step sizes (used for partial derivations, computation of the chi2 in parameter space, etc...) . I used to play with the steps when I was fitting under IDL and I am very surprised I don't find this under python.

It seems obvious that the default steps, which are very small, may lead to a constant chi2 when fitting a rough model... and thus are awkward.

So my question: how to choose the steps when fitting under python ?

Comment: In several optimizers such as ```scipy.optimize.fmin_bfgs```, there is a parameter called ```epsilon``` that controls the step size when the gradient is estimated by finite difference. If you use ```minimize```, you can pass it in the argument ```options``` (dict).

Also, a clear example of input data and what you want to achieve would be better.

Comment: thanks, I will look into options and post a clear example

Answer (score 5):

lmfit's minimizer can wrap several of the optimizers from `scipy.optimize`.  Unfortunately, there is not a very uniform interface to the various solvers, especially for options like step sizes, tolerances, and stopping conditions.  That's partly because the algorithms are actually different, and partly because `scipy.optimize` itself wraps a lot of older code.

That said, the default solver with lmfit is `scipy.optimize.leastsq`, or MINPACK-1, which is very similar to the (very nice, as I recall) MPFIT package for IDL.  As with those codes, you can specify the initial step used for calculating the partial derivatives with `epsfcn`.

To do that with lmfit sort of depends on how you're using lmfit.  One way to do it is

```
result = lmfit.minimize(objective_function, params, args=(x, data),
                        epsfcn=0.001)
```

For a more detailed answer, please give a more detailed question.

Comment: thx. yes, I used mpfit a bunch of times and was happy with it. your 'epsfcn' proposition is a start but it looks this is one absolute step for all variables... I used to control the value, the forward-backward scheme and the relative-absolute scheme for each variable independently...

Comment: Actually, epsfcn is used by MINPACK as a relative change in each parameter's value for estimating the partial derivative for that parameter.  The finite-difference derivative computed in this way are then used to estimate the step taken in the fit.   You don't set the step size per variable with MINPACK/leastsq.  But, short of providing your own derivative function, you will have a difficult time beating its performance.